# Does $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ contain infinite sets?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I know that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is infinite and uncountable. However, is the power set of the natural numbers considered to contain only finite sets of natural numbers, or infinite ones as well?

Comment: What do you means by "group" here? But no matter what, you have that $\mathbb{N} \in \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{N}) $

Comment: Fixed my question, and thanks!

Comment: Notice that contrary to the whole power set, the set of all finite sets is only countable

Comment: @Tryss: you mean _its subset_ of all its finite sets is only countable (there is not such thing as the set of all finite sets). But indeed this is important; without the infinite subsets, what is left of $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is only countable.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It was implicit here that it was the set of all finite sets **of natural numbers**, but you're right that my formulation was imprecise at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Let's pick a few.

- Obviously $\mathbb{N}$ itself
- All the even numbers
- All the odd numbers
- All the prime numbers (these are infinite, right?)

So forth.

(I have exhibited a few infinite sets $\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ thus shown the claim: $\exists S\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with $|S|=|\mathbb{N}|$ which is to say $S$ is countably infinite)